# which one goes first? '\0' or ZeroMemory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have this warning:

> warning C6054: string cAddress may not be zero-terminated

```
bool GSC::bIsValidIPAdd(char *cIPAdd)
{
...........
...........
...........
    ZeroMemory(cAddress, sizeof(cAddress));
    memcpy(cAddress, cIPAdd, strlen(cIPAdd));
    szLength = strlen(cAddress);             //warning here
...........
...........
...........
...........
}
```

if I add this

```
cAddress[0] = '\0';
```

above ZeroMemory the warning is solved...

but... which part of the code should be executed first?
ZeroMemory or '\0'?

Comment: Why are you using memcpy instead of strcpy or strncpy? This seems like an odd choice given that you are using strlen to get the length.

Comment: The analyzer you use just doesn't know anything about ZeroMemory().  it doesn't matter where you put it, nor does it actually solve any problem, it merely shuts up the analyzer.  You could use memset() instead and it will probably be happy.  Or use strcpy, the logical choice here, assuming you next use szLength to write the zero-terminator.

Comment: The habit of doing it always the same.

Comment: Assuming all of the addresses are indeed valid, `cAddress` is statically allocated and thus `sizeof(cAddress)` makes sense, and that `cIPAdd` is null terminated, what about the case where `strlen(cIPAdd) >= sizeof(cAddress)`? `ZeroMemory` won't have zeroed the memory outside `cAddress`'s bounds and there's nothing preventing `memcpy` from overfilling or filling to exactly full and thus writing over the zeroes. What you are doing here just plain doesn't look safe, even if elsewhere you've ensured it is, and the compiler is justified in warning you.

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes from using `memcpy` with strings. You should rely on `strcpy` instead as it will null terminate for you.

There is also a potential problem depending on how you declare `cAddress`.

```
char cAddress[10];
printf("%d\n", sizeof(cAddress));

char* cAddress = "test";
printf("%d\n", sizeof(cAddress));
```

First will print 10, but the second one will print 8 (or 4, if you are on a 32 bits platform).

Comment: char cAddress[16];

Comment: No way for us to know that, @MartinLopez